# VS2013 - Microsoft.Web.Services3 installed but not usable

Tags: c#

A little fresh on the C# train... so this may be a dumb question.

I have installed the WS3.0 SDK.

I have a website created in VS2013.

```
using Microsoft.Web.Services3;
```

Gives me "does not exist in namespace..." error.

Tried adding manually through Add>Reference, but it is not listed anywhere.

I can confirm that a file name Microsoft.Web.Services3 exists in Windows/assembly directory.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is the file the same as the one here? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14089

Comment: @TimFreese Yup that's the one I downloaded and ran setup on

Comment: when you go to add a reference can you add that file by clicking on browse in the reference manager window?

Comment: @TimFreese Nope. It's a .msi file, won't let me select that one or the one in the assembly directory.

Comment: It looks like it exists in nuget.  Try getting it from there.  Right click on references and go to manage nuget packages.  Then search for Microsoft.Web.Services3

Comment: @TimFreese your last comment gave me an idea... and I found it. See answer. And many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found it, in part thanks to @TimFreese.

Went to "Browse" in the reference manager, found the .dll hiding out in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft WSE\v3.0
```